# CRM 2013 field changes are not recognized in Custom Button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a text field that should be filled before custom saving through HTML custom button.
When a user fills this field and tries to save through custom button, the text inside this field is null even if the user fills it. 
Any suggestions Please?

Answer (score 1):

Many Thanks for replying to my query. Actually, I am calling the below function from custom HTML button and I saw the result from alert message as NULL value until I leave the text box.  Once I click some other Field then I am getting right value and saving the record successfully. I have posted my code below please have a look and suggest me how I can achieve it. So how to get the text value if a user doesn't leave the text box and click on the Save button?

```js
function createRecord() {
var oDescription = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_description").getValue();
if (oDescription != null) {
var callentity = {};
var activityId;
var currentUserId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();

var oLeadId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_lead").getValue()[0].id;

callentity.Subject = "Call Activity";
callentity.Description = oDescription ;

XrmSvcToolkit.createRecord({....Some more functions here...

})
}
```

HTML Button code for calling above function

```html
<input id="SaveCall" onclick="parent.createRecord()" type="button" value="Save Phonecall"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute(arg).getValue(val)` won't return a value until focus is lost from the `arg` attribute (as you've found out).

Some options you could try:

1. `document.getElementById('new_description_i')[0].value`
2. Removing [focus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) from `"new_description"` on click of your button.

Comment: Hi Dave, Many Thanks for replying on my question.Below is my code please have a look and suggest me how I can achieve it.

Comment: No even it doesn't work but I tried focussing cursor onto other field and ends up in two clicks to save the record.

Comment: I think there is no better way to achieve it.